# Ssas cube wizard doesn't create measures for fact table columns

Tags: database, ssas, data-warehouse, olap-cube

When I create a ssas cube, I don't get any measure columns in fact table. The only measure is Fact table count value. I don't understand why. Then when I add a dimension fact table fields appear in the dimension. There is only a count field which is not a column in Fact table.

I have tried several times to create but the wizard doesn't give me the right columns to choose. What do I do, please?

Fact table columns are human_fatalities, number_of_service_hour_lost , other_cost,service_cost,Surrogate_keys to the different dimensions.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the measure columns?   Are they exposed in the Data Source View?

Comment: yes i have in datasource view but i think variables are in varchar it's why it's not getting

Comment: Variables are Displayed, Measure columns are in varchar(300). Do you think this is the problem

Comment: That is correct, the wizard will only suggest numeric columns for measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wizard will only suggest numeric columns for measures.   If you cannot change the table, perhaps you can create a view that casts the columns as a numeric data type.  If that is not possible, you can create computed columns in your Data Source View that convert the measure columns to a numeric data type.